# How can I apply the `|` operand to a string?

Tags: c#, class, try-catch, or-operator

I am having trouble with this line of code right here...why am I being prompted with this error? I am getting an error saying `"Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'` How do check if my residency variable is not equal to these 2 strings I have listed in the if statement?

```
catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                if (age > 16 | age > 80)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You can only enter states of OH or MI ad the driver's age must be between 16 and 80.");
                }
                if (residency != "OH" | "MI")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You can only enter states of OH or MI ad the driver's age must be between 16 and 80.");
                }
            }
```

Here is the full code if you want to get a better idea of what I am trying to execute.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CarInsurance create = new CarInsurance();
            Console.Write("Enter the age of the driver: ");
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the state the driver lives in: ");
            string residence = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            create.PremiumCalculate(age, residence);
        }
    }
    class CarInsurance
    {
        public int driverAge { get; set; }
        public string residency { get; set; }
        public int totalPremium;

        public int GetPremium()
        {
            return totalPremium;
        }
        public void PremiumCalculate(int age, string residency)
        {
            int premiumOhio = 100;
            int premiumMichigan = 250;
            try
            {
                if (residency == "MI")
                {
                    int total = (100 - age) * 3 + premiumMichigan;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your premium is {0}", total.ToString("C"));
                }
                if (residency == "OH")
                {
                    int total = (100 - age) * 3 + premiumOhio;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your premium is {0}", total.ToString("C"));
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                if (age > 16 | age > 80)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You can only enter states of OH or MI ad the driver's age must be between 16 and 80.");
                }
                if (residency != "OH" | "MI")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You can only enter states of OH or MI ad the driver's age must be between 16 and 80.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do the same thing you do when using it with an `int` (and use the `||` operator instead of `|`)

Answer (score 2):

You should apply it between two conditions, not values. Note

```
if (residency != "OH" || residency != "MI")
```

Note, however, that this condition will always return `true`. You probably meant to use `&&`:

```
if (residency != "OH" && residency != "MI")
```

Comment: Neither of my exception blocks are being thrown when I enter in something that shouldn't be. I have entered an 11 year old as a driver and I'm not being thrown the following `Console.WriteLine` statement that it should be and I have also tried an 81 year old and I still had no exception come up. I have also tried entering a residency that wasn't OH or MI and I the exception was not thrown.

Comment: @dorlox: You need to read up on what an exception means in C#.  A `catch` statement will only catch `exceptions` that are `thrown` from the current code, or from code that the current code calls (directly or indirectly).  You need to remove the try/catch and put your error checking in the regular code

Comment: I moved the main method code into the try and except block so it could catch those exceptions...and it's not catching those exceptions.

Comment: That's because there is no `ArgumentException` being thrown in the code. Probably would be best to remove the `try/catch` if you don't know what exceptions are thrown, and then add the `catch` blocks as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain the issue first. Here `residency != "OH" | "MI"`, you are evaluating `residency != "OH"` and this works and produces `bool`. Then produced `bool` fails against `| "MI"` because operator `|` is invalid for strings.

If you had 2 strings, you would get

> Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

One way to fix it is

```cs
using System.Linq;
. . .. 
var exclusionList = new [] {"OH","MI"};
if (!exclusionList.Contains(residency))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.  First, I start off by listing all states (yeah, you only care about two of them, but any of them is a valid state):

```
public enum ResidentState
{
    AL,
    AK,
    AZ,
    AR,
    CA,
    CO,
    CT,
    DE,
    FL,
    GA,
    HI,
    ID,
    IL,
    IN,
    IA,
    KS,
    KY,
    LA,
    ME,
    MD,
    MA,
    MI,
    MN,
    MS,
    MO,
    MT,
    NE,
    NV,
    NH,
    NJ,
    NM,
    NY,
    NC,
    ND,
    OH,
    OK,
    OR,
    PA,
    RI,
    SC,
    SD,
    TN,
    TX,
    UT,
    VT,
    VA,
    WA,
    WV,
    WI,
    WY,
}
```

Then I start my car insurance class:

```
class CarInsurance
{
    public int DriverAge { get; private set; }
    public ResidentState Residency { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPremium { get; private set; }

    private bool _ageOk = false;
    private bool _residencyOk = false;
}
```

It has publicly readable properties for DriverAge, ResidentState and TotalPremium.  They can only be set from within the class.  It also has a few bookkeeping flags for age and residency validity.

Then, I add a couple of member functions to that class to set the DriverAge and Residency.  They do error checking. They both have the same pattern.  They will return false unless you set them correctly:

```
 public bool SetResidency(ResidentState residency)
 {
     if (residency != ResidentState.OH && residency != ResidentState.MI)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("You can only enter states of OH or MI");
         return false;
     }

     Residency = residency;
     _residencyOk = true;
     return true;
 }

 public bool SetDriverAge(int age)
 {
     if (age < 16 || age > 80)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("The driver's age must between 16 and 80.");
         return false;
     }

     _ageOk = true;
     DriverAge = age;
     return true;
 }
```

If the caller is using these correctly, then _ageOk and _residencyOk will be true.  They may be false if not.

Then I create the CalculatePremium function to that class (and a few constants) (note, I renamed it to be verb-noun, I think it makes more sense):

```
private const int PremiumOhio = 100;
private const int PremiumMichigan = 250;

public int CalculatePremium()
{
    if (!_residencyOk)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The driver's residency must first be entered, and only Ohio and Michigan are valid states");
    }

    if (!_ageOk)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The driver's age must first be entered, and it must be between 16 and 80");
    }

    int premium;
    switch (Residency)
    {
        case ResidentState.MI:
            premium = PremiumMichigan;
            break;
        case ResidentState.OH:
            premium = PremiumOhio;
            break;
        default:
            premium = 10_000;
            break;
    }

    TotalPremium = (100 - DriverAge) * 3 + premium;
    Console.WriteLine($"Your total premium is {TotalPremium:C}");
    return TotalPremium;
}
```

Finally, I wrote the Program class that has the Main function:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CarInsurance insurance = new CarInsurance();
        bool ageOk = false;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the age of the driver: ");
            var response = Console.ReadLine();
            ageOk = int.TryParse(response, out var age);
            if (!ageOk)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must enter an integer for age");
            }
            else
            {
                ageOk = insurance.SetDriverAge(age);
            }
        } while (!ageOk);

        bool stateOk = false;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the state the driver lives in: ");
            var stateStr = Console.ReadLine();
            stateOk = Enum.TryParse<ResidentState>(stateStr, true, out var state);
            if (!stateOk)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The state you entered ({stateStr}) is not a valid two-letter state abbreviation");
            }
            else
            {
                stateOk = insurance.SetResidency(state);
            }

        } while (!stateOk);

        var premium = insurance.CalculatePremium();
    }
}
```

Note that I check that the entered data is a valid integer (or a valid state abbreviation) in this code.  Then I check (using the Insurance class) that it is valid for this calculation.  As it's written, it will not cause either of the exceptions within CalculatePremium to be thrown.  However, it might make sense to wrap the call to CalculatePremium in a try/catch.  I'll leave that up to you - you really need to read up on exceptions.

I wrote this is a way (and explained it in a way), that will allow you to explore some of the features of the language.  Step through it in the debugger.  Enter invalid entries for both quantities (something that's not an integer, and then something that's out of range for age, and something that's not a state and then not either MI or OH) and see what happens.  Try calling calculate premium with invalid values and see what happens (and try to catch the result).

Comment: I tried putting this into a new IDE and I'm just getting thrown a lot of errors...could you show me what your entire code looks like with out chopping it up?

Comment: Create a new console app.  Replace the `Program` class with mine.  Then add a new class to your project, name it `CarInsurance`.  Replace the empty class with what I show. Then add `SetResidency`, `SetDriverAge` and `CalculatePremium` as members of that `CarInsurance` class.  Be sure to include the two `const int`s in that class.  Finally, add a new class to your project called `ResidentState`.  In the file, through away the entire class (including the `class` statement) and replace it with my enum.  At that point, you should have no errors.  If you have errors figure them out

Comment: By the way, it *chopped it up* so that I could explain it.  Had I just pasted all the code in, I suspect you'd have a really hard time figuring out my code