# Try and Catch blocks not throwing anything

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have created an `ArgumetException` catch block and it is not throwing anything when I input something it is supposed to catch...how do I fix this? For example if I input the driver age as 15 or 81 it still goes through with out being caught and it calculates the final premium. I also would enter their state of residency that isn't Ohio or Michigan and my catch block is not catching anything. I don't know if you can understand what I'm trying to say but if you copy and paste this into your IDE and try running it your self I think you'll understand it a bit more.

Here is the code

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CarInsurance create = new CarInsurance();
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the age of the driver: ");
                int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter the state the driver lives in: ");
                string residence = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                create.PremiumCalculate(age, residence);
            }
            catch (FormatException) // catches if user inputs a string instead of a value
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a numeric value for the age of the driver!");
            }
        }
    }
    class CarInsurance
    {
        public int driverAge { get; set; } // gets and sets driver age
        public string residency { get; set; } // gets and sets residency
        public int totalPremium;

        public int GetPremium() // gets the premium ***readonly***
        {
            return totalPremium;
        }
        public void PremiumCalculate(int age, string residency) // main method for CarInurance class
        {
            int premiumOhio = 100;
            int premiumMichigan = 250;
            try
            {
                if (residency == "MI")
                {
                    int total = (100 - age) * 3 + premiumMichigan;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your premium is {0}", total.ToString("C"));
                }
                if (residency == "OH")
                {
                    int total = (100 - age) * 3 + premiumOhio;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your premium is {0}", total.ToString("C"));
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                if (age < 16 && age > 80)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You can only enter states of OH or MI ad the driver's age must be between 16 and 80.");
                }
                if (residency != "OH" && residency != "MI")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You can only enter states of OH or MI ad the driver's age must be between 16 and 80.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The final `try-catch` block at the bottom of the code is what I am having a problem with.

Comment: There is no `throw` anywhere in your code, and there is nothing in the `try` section in `PremiumCalculate` that I would expect to throw an `ArgumentException`, so I wouldn't expect the `catch` to ever be executed.

Comment: It seems that this has already been explained to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197187/how-can-i-apply-the-operand-to-a-string#comment108262031_61197232). I recommend reading the [try-catch documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) in full.